# find Anagrams words using Regxp in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

An anagram group is a group of words such that any one can be converted into any other just by rearranging the letters. For example, `"rats"`, `"tars"` and `"star"` are an anagram group.

Now I have an array of words and I am going to find the anagram words
to find this I have written the following code

actually it works for some words like *scar* and *cars*, but it doesn't work 
for   [*scar* , *carts*].

```
temp=[]
words.each do |e|

    temp=e.split(//)                       # make an array of letters

    words.each do |z|
         if  z.match(/#{temp}/)            # match to find scar and cars
                 puts "exp is True" 
         else
                 puts "exp is false" 
         end     
    end

end
```

I just think that while `[abc]` means `a or b or c`  I can separate my words to letters and then look for other cases in the array

Comment: what's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm is incorrect and inefficient (quadratic time complexity). Why regex?

Here's another idea. Define the *signature* of a word such that all the letters of a word are sorted. For example, the signature of `hello` is `ehllo`.

By this definition, anagrams are words that have the same signature, for example, `rats`, `tars` and `star` all have the signature `arst`. The code to implement this idea is straight-forward.

Comment: I'm not sure that any code can be both incorrect and inefficient, but we know what you mean...

Answer (score 2):

Two words are anagrams if they contain the same letters. There are several ways to figure out whether they do, the most obvious one is sorting the letters alphabetically. Then you want to separate the words into groups. Here's an idea:

```
words = %w[cats scat rats tars star scar cars carts]

words.group_by {|word| word.each_char.sort }.values
# => [['cats', 'scat'], ['rats', 'tars', 'star'], ['scar', 'cars'], ['carts']]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `/#{e.split(//)}/` here is pretty much nonsensical.

To illustrate this, lets see what happens:

```
word    = 'wtf'
letters = word.split(//) # => ["w", "t", "f"]
regex   = /#{letters}/   # => /["w", "t", "f"]/
'"'.match(regex) # => 0
','.match(regex) # => 0
' '.match(regex) # => 0
't'.match(regex) # => 0
```

What happens is interpolating something in a regex replaces it with the result of its `to_s` method. And since [character sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) match a single character in what's inside, you will get a regex that matches `"` or `,` or  or any of the letters in the original word.

---

Therefore, I will unfortunately call your solution unsalvageable.

A very easy way to check if two words are anagrams is to sort their characters and see if the result is the same.

Comment: Good point, ⩗. I think you can strike "pretty much" and "unfortunately".

Answer (score 0):

The faster way would be:

```
def is_anagram? w1, w2
  w1.chars.sort == w2.chars.sort
end
```

You could also do something like this I suppose:

```
def is_anagram? w1, w2
  w2 = w2.chars
  w1.chars.permutation.to_a.include?(w2)
end
```

then run it like this:

```
is_anagram? "rats", "star"
=> true
```

*Note:*
This post has been edited as per Cary Swoveland's advice.

Comment: `word2.split('')` is executed for each permutation. Even with that fixed,I think you should strike "yet". :-)

Comment: I wondered why you didn't mention your second method (sorting) first, as it's clearly superior, until I noticed you added that later, after sorting had been mentioned by others. Not good, as it left the impression that it was your idea. You should have written (sic), "Edit: As mentioned by others, a better way..That could be implemented as follows.."

Comment: I actually am out and thought of the second way while taking a stroll. Didn't know that anagram algorithm had a patent on it, apologies.

Comment: I am not being critical. Whenever you edit to add an alternative approach you need to see if it has been suggested by someone else. If it has, either don't mention it or state that it has been suggested by others. If you don't, readers who recall your initial answer (or check the edit history) may conclude that you are being devious, which is the last thing you want. Why might they think that? Because there are some at SO whose ethics are in the gutter.

Answer (score 0):

```
words =  ['demo', 'none', 'tied', 'evil', 'dome', 'mode', 'live',
          'fowl', 'veil', 'wolf', 'diet', 'vile', 'edit', 'tide',
          'flow', 'neon']

groups = words.group_by { |word| word.split('').sort }
groups.each { |x, y| p y }
```